# Facebook iframe content doesn't show up about 80% of the time, but only on this particular site

Tags: facebook, tumblr

Is this a tumblr issue? This is my first time using tumblr... about 1/8 the time my facebook content shows up and the rest of the time you just see a white box

here is the URL in question

http://nickladieu.com/

Here is a link to the issue in case it shows up for you (BTW tested in multiple browsers on multiple computers... shows up sometimes, sometimes does not show up)

http://img821.imageshack.us/f/tumblrissue.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever plugin/code you're using to generate you're using to generate those buttons, the iframe associated with it is using a height of "px" with no value next to it. Fixing that even if it's just with css might sort out your problem. For your reference, here's the code that gets generated (notice the height attributed):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=
http%3A%2F%2Fnickladieu.com%2Fpost%2F3878815532%2Fwhat-do-you-guys-think-of-hootsuite&amp;layout=button_count&amp;
show_faces=false&amp;width=98&amp;action=like&amp;
colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; 
overflow:visible; width:98px; height:px; float:left"></iframe>
```

My suggestions would be to use a service called "Addthis" or even "Sharethis" to generate your buttons; they even give you instructions on how to install it. Personally, I'm using "addthis" on a theme that I've just released for sale - for a demo, check out [Essentialight](http://essentialight.tumblr.com/).

Comment: I gave you the mark up. The height was in fact wrong, however facebooks own iframe examples on their website are also blank most of the time. I was able to fix this by using the javascript include method.   

Just on a side note I don't like "add this" because it has a bunch of crap in it. The only 2 that matter are facebook and twitter in my world.  I suppose you could make an argument for stumble upon and digg as well